# passing from spark to velocity

Tags: java, templates, velocity, spark-java

I am new to Spark, and I am using it with the velocity template engine.

```
get("/", (request, response) -> {
   return new ModelAndView(new HashMap(), "/index.html"); 
}, new VelocityTemplateEngine());
```

Works fine, as the examples on the site, displays my HTML correctly.

I need to get a piece of text onto my template. I have managed this by using sets on the actual template just fine - but how can I pass from my spark (java) to the velocity template?

I'm not trying to get anything complicated onto this velocity template- just a simple string or integer.

I tried looking at some examples, but nothing is happening- many of the examples seem to have a different set up from myself. The code I am trying-

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
                    context.put("test", "string");
                    return new ModelAndView(context, "/index.vtl");
```

I want to use test as the name and string as the value, like #set ($test = "string"). This seems something very simple- I am used to doing this with things like Flask, but I'm having trouble finding an example with spark. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

your first code is correct 100% but you have to fill the needed values to pass in a java Map:

```
get("/", (request, response) -> {
Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("name", "Some name");
return new ModelAndView(values, "/index.html"); 
}, new VelocityTemplateEngine());
```

and the VelocityTemplateEngine is a class from Spark that will handle setting your values into the Velocity context and render the template.